# Getting the outer node based on the inner node value with XSLT XPATH

Tags: xslt, xpath

Im have the following XML:

```
<elements>
<a>
 <b>b1</b>
 <c>
  <d>d1</d>
 </c>
</a>
<a>
 <b>b2</b>
 <c>
  <d>d2</d>
 </c>
</a>
</elements>
```

I have an xslt template, where I try to get the first  content (in this case, b1) where its inner  content equals to something.
I tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="elements/a[c/d = d1]/b" />
```

But it fails to work. I expect to get b1, yet I get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the string *d1*:

```
<xsl:value-of select="elements/a[c/d = 'd1']/b" />
```

Comment: thanks. Dont know how I didnt think of the quotes. I started getting some strange ideas.